# Running tests on fresh 8.2.x install throws "Permission Denied" for Kernel tests

Tags: 8, testing

Under a fresh install of 8.2.x, when I run tests, only Kernel tests seem to fail with this message from the testing UI:

```
(path/to/test/Kernel/test.php) ... Permission denied
```

Pretty much any Kernel test I select exits immediately with that error. Other tests, like Unit tests, work fine. Is this a file permission issue or something I missed in config?

Comment: Perhaps https://www.drupal.org/node/2760905?

Comment: Running from the UI though. Same deal? Trying from console now.

Comment: Can you specify an exact test you can reproduce this with so others can try it out too?  I don't recall why I did it, but I have `drush -y en basic_auth` in my setup script for Drupal 8 dev.  Want to try with and without with a test that fails for you.

Comment: Using the testing UI, if I select migrate drupal 6 for example, all tests fail with that error. Is this a problem with the UI, and should I only use CLI?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like some tests can only be ran with the command line and will not work with the test runner UI.